# Excel Automatic Calculation Setting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, user-defined-functions

I have a complex project in `Microsoft Office Excel 2007' which utilises a large number of UDFs. Through VBA in a **Workbook_Open** Event, I set Excel Automatic calculation to OFF and a strategically placed **Calculate** method to manually calculate the cells whenever I need it so that the UDF doesn't perform recalculation unintentionally.

If the workbook is the **ONLY** one opened (or the **first** to open) in an Excel instance, everything works perfect. Only when it's opened **AFTER** another workbook (within the same instance), my project will inherit the Automatic calculation setting from the **FIRST** workbook and perform endless calculation on my UDFs. The disable code placed in the Workbook_Open event isn't executed until the UDF finishes the calculation (which can take forever). This only happens if my project is **NOT** the one opened first.

Through http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretse.htm, I discover that it is the nature of Excel to perform the calculation process **BEFORE** the Workbook_Open event is executed.

So the question I have obviously relates to the project being opened **AFTER** another workbook is opened with automatic calculation turned ON:

1. How do I force my project to **disable** automatic calculation
   without it performing recalculation first (remember, problem only
   occurs when the project not the first one to be opened since it will
   follow settings from previously opened workbook) **OR**...
2. How do I get the project to open in ANOTHER INSTANCE (when double clicked) to avoid
   inheriting automatic calculation setting from the previous workbook.

Either way, the answer I'm seeking is for the project to open without performing the calculation first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a different workbook (Opener.xls) to initiate opening the UDF workbook (udf.xls)

in Opener.xls the Workbook_Open code
- sets calculation to manual
- opens udf.xls

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for the answer. The client think it would be too much to keep additional file because this project will be used in hundreds of computers. It is not possible to keep asking the user to open the project through another file. I personally think it's a good idea, but just not what the client looking for. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

In your question I don't recognize the way you use to change and inherit that option to your workbooks, But I answer it as a solution:

Use VBA and running VBA macros to change that option for just your active sheet as soon as you need to calculate; by using it like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
  .EnableCalculation = False
  .EnableCalculation = True
  .Calculate
End With
```

In another ways that may you need, you can read [this part of MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx#sectionSection3).