# MS Excel HYPERLINK() function with dynamic link_location does not work - why?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to include the spreadsheet's own filename in an e-mail body dynamically created with the following formula including a VBA Module (?) function:

```
=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&"address"&"?subject="&B7&"&body="&B7&FullName(); "E-Mail")
```

The function is

```
Function FullName() As String
    FullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName()
End Function
```

in a "module" of the document (I don't have a clue about VBA: ALT+F11, Insert Module. Apparently this is also called user defined function ([UDF](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel))).

The function works on its own in a cell, the HYPERLINK formula works without adding to its link_location the function, but together (as above), it evaluates to

```
#NAME?
```

Links:

- Office docs: [HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)
- possibly related, but somewhat reverse problem: [VBA to open Excel hyperlink does not work when hyperlink generated with a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422003/vba-to-open-excel-hyperlink-does-not-work-when-hyperlink-generated-with-a-formul)
- [Hyperlink custom link_location formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469599/hyperlink-custom-link-location-formula) is not dynamic
- Very similar problem: [Creating a custom hyperlink function in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560742/creating-a-custom-hyperlink-function-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24836716/1619432) from the latter link in the question (do not use HYPERLINK formula, instead a function changes the manually created link in the cell).

Comment: Depending on settings, this cell/function may not be evaluated automatically. Forcing this for the cell with `Calculate` does not seem to always work when called in the `Workbook.BeforeSave` event / function. Modifying the settings there does work for me, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29094142/1619432